# Putting docker run parameters into Dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a working docker command:

```
 docker run -p 3001:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /Users/thomas/Desktop/digital-ocean-jenkins/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

I'd like to put these config variables in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
EXPOSE 3001 8080 
EXPOSE 50000 50000
VOLUME jenkins:var/jenkins_home
```

However it's not taking any of these configuration variables. How can I pass in the parameters I am passing to `docker run` as apart of the build?

I built and ran using this:

```
docker build -t treggi-jenkins .
docker run treggi-jenkins
```

Comment: You can't put the port to be used on the host that runs the container into the `Dockerfile`, you can merely declare which ports you can use with the `-p` option later. Same for volumes, see [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume). If you want to declare that, try docker compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd need to use docker-compose for something like that.
See [docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/)

The docker-compose file could look something like this

```
version: '3'

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    ports:
      - "3001:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - jenkins:var/jenkins_home

  volumes:
    jenkins:
```